# Assembly - how to increase a variable by 2

Tags: variables, assembly, x86, tasm

How do I increase a variable by 2? 
I am using Assembly x86 and TASM.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
.stack 100h
.data
  my_var dw ?
.code      
  mov  ax,@data
  mov  ds,ax

  mov  my_var, 5
  add  my_var, 2         ;<=== INCREASE BY 2 ( 5+2 ).

  mov  ax,4c00h
  int  21h
```

If you are using IDEAL mode :

```
  add  [ my_var ], 2     ;<=== INCREASE BY 2 ( 5+2 ).
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel really dumb, I completely forgot about the 'add' command.